# Predetermine the cells with the data to send emails

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I found the code below.

The code asks for the range with the data to be selected and sends the emails. I tried to predetermine these cells but I could not figure it out.

Example

This is my table, I do not want to select the cells every time I run the code, instead I would like the code take the data from cells A2:C6

[image: This is my table, I do not want to select the cells everytime I run the code, instead of that I would like to predetermine to always when I run the code the macro will take the data from cells A2:C6]

The code:

```
Sub SendEMail()
'update by Extendoffice 20160506
Dim xEmail As String
Dim xSubj As String
Dim xMsg As String
Dim xURL As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Double
Dim xCell As Range
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xTxt As String
On Error Resume Next
xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the data range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If xRg.Columns.Count <> 3 Then
    MsgBox " Regional format error, please check", , "Kutools for Excel"
    Exit Sub
End If
For i = 1 To xRg.Rows.Count
'       Get the email address
    xEmail = xRg.Cells(i, 2)
'       Message subject
    xSubj = "Your Registration Code"
'       Compose the message
    xMsg = ""
    xMsg = xMsg & "Dear " & xRg.Cells(i, 1) & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    xMsg = xMsg & " This is your Registration Code "
    xMsg = xMsg & xRg.Cells(i, 3).Text & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    xMsg = xMsg & " please try it, and glad to get your feedback! " & vbCrLf
    xMsg = xMsg & "Skyyang"
'       Replace spaces with %20 (hex)
    xSubj = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xSubj, " ", "%20")
    xMsg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xMsg, " ", "%20")
'       Replace carriage returns with %0D%0A (hex)
    xMsg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xMsg, vbCrLf, "%0D%0A")
'       Create the URL
    xURL = "mailto:" & xEmail & "?subject=" & xSubj & "&body=" & xMsg
'       Execute the URL (start the email client)
    ShellExecute 0&, vbNullString, xURL, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus
'       Wait two seconds before sending keystrokes
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    Application.SendKeys "%s"
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace :

```
Dim xTxt As String
On Error Resume Next
xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the data range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If xRg.Columns.Count <> 3 Then
    MsgBox " Regional format error, please check", , "Kutools for Excel"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

by :

```
Set xRg = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:C6")
```

I've included `On Error Resume Next` because if your code runs into an error, you'll not see it and hence cannot correct it to correct it!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the data range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
```

use the line

```
Set xRg = Range("A2:C6")
```

Comment: I do have a doubt guys, I Edited my text asking for further questions, should I click on the edit button and put my question there or click on Answer your question button and type my question? I am a little confused about this

Comment: If you have a follow up question, I would suggest a new question. At the end of your new question you can link to this one, and be clear about the new question and the (answered) old one.