# How to improve this VBA code to add Carbon Copy into it

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to improve my code my from previous post [Predetermine the cells with the data to send emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495737/how-can-i-adapt-this-vba-code-to-predetermine-the-cells-with-the-data-to-send-em) to put some Carbon Copy (CC) on the line code. What I am trying to figure out is that there are some companies that might be my CC's, that depends of the type of email I want to send.

Example: I created 2 lists of CC emails That I might wanna send emails.

[image]

In front of the company's name I Concatenate all the emails from the list to only one cell.

How can I put this into the code that I can choose the name of the company and all the emails from that company goes to the CC list?

Thank you one more time for all the helping you guys are giving me.

I am going to copy the code from the previous post just to be easier to read:

```
Sub SendEMail()
'update by Extendoffice 20160506
Dim xEmail As String
Dim xSubj As String
Dim xMsg As String
Dim xURL As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Double
Dim xCell As Range
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xTxt As String
On Error Resume Next
xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
Set xRg = Range("A2:C6")
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For i = 1 To xRg.Rows.Count
'       Get the email address
        xEmail = xRg.Cells(i, 2)
'       Message subject
        xSubj = "Your Registration Code"
'       Compose the message
    xMsg = ""
    xMsg = xMsg & "Dear " & xRg.Cells(i, 1) & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    xMsg = xMsg & " This is your Registration Code "
    xMsg = xMsg & xRg.Cells(i, 3).Text & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    xMsg = xMsg & " please try it, and glad to get your feedback! " & vbCrLf
    xMsg = xMsg & "Skyyang"
'       Replace spaces with %20 (hex)
    xSubj = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xSubj, " ", "%20")
    xMsg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xMsg, " ", "%20")
'       Replace carriage returns with %0D%0A (hex)
    xMsg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xMsg, vbCrLf, "%0D%0A")
'       Create the URL
    xURL = "mailto:" & xEmail & "?subject=" & xSubj & "&body=" & xMsg
'       Execute the URL (start the email client)
    ShellExecute 0&, vbNullString, xURL, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus
'       Wait two seconds before sending keystrokes
             Application.DisplayKeys "%s"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You would want a field in your data set that identifies what company is associated with the e-mail you are sending to (which could potentially be derived from the associated e-mail domain if that is a consistent way to find the company). Then when running the macro you could lookup the list of CC's based on the company field you defined and add it to the xURL string with something like "&cc=" & xCCs (I don't know the actual format you would need for the URL, that's just an example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-In your code after:

```
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

insert:

```
Dim CCCompany As Integer
Dim ccstr As String

ccstr = FindMyCompany()

If ccstr = vbNullString Then
    CCCompany = MsgBox("No cc email selected. Are you sure you want to proceed?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "To be or not to be")
    If CCCompany = vbYes Then
        xCC = ""
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    xCC = "&cc=" & ccstr
End If
```

2-Then replace:

```
xURL = "mailto:" & xEmail & "?subject=" & xSubj & "&body=" & xMsg
```

with:

```
xURL = "mailto:" & xEmail & "?subject=" & xSubj & xCC & "&body=" & xMsg
```

3-Finally add below function after your sub:

```
Function FindMyCompany() As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim xCC As String
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select desired Company column or any cell in that column", _
"Get Company Column", Type:=8)
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    i = 1
    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, rng.Column))
    Set crng = Cells(i, rng.Column)
        If InStr(crng.Value, "@") Then
            xCC = xCC & crng.Value & ";"
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    FindMyCompany = Left(xCC, Len(xCC) - 1)
End Function
```

4-Allocate your Companies along with email addresses to different columns as shown below. You can set as many company as you need this way.

[image]

5-When you run your code, simply select your desired company cell and click ok.

Important note: You can select the whole column, a range of cells from desired column or a single cell in the desired column. Your code will still work since it extracts only column number from your selection.

**Edit:** If you want to repeat this process for selecting bcc emails, right after selecting ccs, you can use the same function with different assignment like this:

```
Dim CCCompany As Integer
Dim ccstr As String
Dim bccstr As String

ccstr = FindMyCompany()
bccstr = FindMyCompany()

If ccstr = vbNullString Then
    CCCompany = MsgBox("No cc email selected. Are you sure you want to proceed?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "To be or not to be")
    If CCCompany = vbYes Then
        xCC = ""
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    xCC = "&cc=" & ccstr
End If
If bccstr = vbNullString Then
    BCCCompany = MsgBox("No cc email selected. Are you sure you want to proceed?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "To be or not to be")
    If BCCCompany = vbYes Then
        xBCC = ""
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    xBCC = "&bcc=" & bccstr
End If
```

and amend your `xURL` like this

```
xURL = "mailto:" & xEmail & "?subject=" & xSubj & xCC & xBCC & "&body=" & xMsg
```

Comment: Perfectly worked, If I wanna do the same process to CCO ( Carbon Copy Occult), Do I have to create a new function and repeat the same steps that you showed me? You helped me a lot, thank you very much for that

Answer (score 0):

The short answer (albeit somewhat janky) might be to:

- Make Column D you "cc" column which will point to the concatenated value of the cc's (C10)
- make an `xCC = xRg.Cells(i, 4)`
- make `xURL = "mailto:" & xEmail & "?subject=" & xSubj & "&body=" & xMsg  & "&cc=" & xCC`

I do want to point out that this is prone to becoming a mess, but it should solve your immediate need.

I would recommend the solution below for a better approach:

Create 2 new columns (let's say J and K). J will hold the Name of the companies, (like XCCompany) and K will hold a single email address corresponding to the company. In your example you would do this three times for each company (since they both have three cc's and end up with six records) -- the company name will be the same for three but the email addresses will be different. We want the company names to be the same so that we can search on them.

ADDITIONALLY, in column D you can store the name of the company to CC (XCCompany) and when you press the button the macro will lookup email addresses that correspond to the company name (using the info in J and K), concatenate them, and put them as cc's. I found a nifty little UDF function that does this http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/345-LookUp-Value-and-Concatenate-All-Found-Results.

**If you wanted to take this approach**, declare the function in a module (maybe under your SendEmail function) and instead of setting xCC as indicated above, set it as indicated below (make sure to keep the changes to xURL):

```
xCC = LookUpConcat(xRg.Cells(i, 4), Range("J2:J100"), Range("K2:K100"), ";")
```

(Note I only went up to K100 and J100 for performance issues, your list could grow longer and if so, you would want to adjust accordingly.)

Good Luck!